# correct order of pseudo classes

Tags: html, css, navigation

hey there i created a little navigation:

```
        <ul class="fancyNav">
            <li id="home"><a href="#home" class="homeIcon">Home</a></li>
            <li id="news"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
```

here:

http://jsfiddle.net/haskelluser/rECnm/35/

:hover is working great, you can see

now i want every time a listelement is selected to get it another color with pseudoclass active?(which color is not important, just for functionality)

but mine doesnt work, you know why? could help me ? greetings

Comment: Can you have a `active` pseudo class on a non-anchor?

Comment: i think so or? how should i solve this if not with a pseudo class?

Comment: The question is not clear: do you want a different hover color for each element of the navigation bar? Is this what you mean by *select*?

Comment: no, if you click on a listelement it should get a new color. this color should stay at this element until you click an other listelement, u understand?

Comment: you could post a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `target` pseudo class: when you activate the link, the fragment of the URL changes targeting the element which has that id.

So, this should work:

```
.fancyNav li:target{
    /*properties here*/
}
```

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/rECnm/36/.

Comment: ehm sorry but your fiddle is same like mine, why?